# Server structure for Web application

Tags: web-services, rest, http, webserver, application-server

I have a web application w1 (SPA):
The webserver WS is located in a physical server X
The applicationserver AS il located in an other physical server Y.

The user call the the webserver to start w1 application (http://WS/w1)
Non the browser have the view, but not the data.
To retrieve data w1 applicatio call AS by ajax http GET calls (http://AS/car/df785er/plate  for example to retrie a plate of a car)

Summing, in a MVC design, the View is retrieved from WS, the Model is retrieved from AS.

This structure is correct? Or the correct structure is have WS and AS inn the same physical machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure of your application is correct... BUT the browser by default will block, for security reasons, the ajax requests made to the model AS.

There are several possible solutions. Those I've used are:

1. enable CORS on AS server. 
   This will allow the browser to make calls to AS
   It's really easy if you only make GET requests. You simply add an http header (Access-Control-Allow-Origin:) to the response
   For details on CORS: 
   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS
2. Use a reverse proxy on WS to make calls to AS: eg. all requests to /api/ on WS will be reverse proxyed to http://AS/

Which solution to apply depends on security considerations, what type of requests you are making (eg. CORS only allows GET, HEAD amd POST), etc...

Comment: Grazie Filippo! I'm already using CORS. 
My problem is that I use cookie to resend to AS a sessionid... I call my application server to retrieve for example an attachment by a direct http GET without custom ajax call (the user only press a link) and not always the GET send my sessionid cookie

Comment: By your 2nd solution I think that the problem would be solved